# I have installed version 2.3 of glibc forcefully, and after that i am not able to run any linux cmd, as it ask for glibc 2.4

Tags: linux, version, glibc, rhel5

```
[root@localhost Keystone2]# sudo rpm -ivh glibc-2.3.4-2.9.audit.x86_64.rpm --nodeps --force
warning: glibc-2.3.4-2.9.audit.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID db42a60e
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:glibc                  warning: /etc/localtime created as /etc/localtime.rpmnew
########################################### [100%]
/usr/sbin/iconvconfig: relocation error: /lib64/tls/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_out_of_memory, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
/usr/sbin/glibc_post_upgrade: While trying to execute /usr/sbin/iconvconfig.x86_64 child exited with exit code 127
error: %post(glibc-2.3.4-2.9.audit.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 127


**version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by /lib64/libselinux.so.1)**
```

Comment: Please help me in solving this issue, as I can't run any command

Answer (score 0):

> I have installed version 2.3 of glibc forcefully

... and now you know why it was not a good idea to do so. Package dependencies are there for a *reason*. If you forcefully violate them, you may break your system (and have broken it).

> Please help me in solving this issue, as I can't run any command

The only way to recover is to

- boot from recovery CD
- mount your root file system
- reinstall glibc-2.4
- reboot